# How to implement reduceRight function in Typescript in Lazy Evaluation Paradigm

Tags: typescript, functional-programming, lazy-evaluation

I need help implementing reduceRight function im confused for a basic reduceRight I just take a list reverse it and call reduce function on it and get the required output but I don't know how to do the same thing in Lazy Eval paradigm. Following is my reduceRigth code

```
interface LazySequence<T> {
   value: T;
   next(): LazySequence<T>;
}

 ----------------------------------------------------------------

 function reduceRight<T>(func: (v:T, t: T)=>T, seq: LazySequence<T>, start:T): T{
    while (seq.next() === undefined){
    return reduceRight(func,seq,func(start,seq.value));
    }
    reduceRight(func,seq.next(),func(start,seq.value));
 }
```

Comment: Are you not using `--strictNullChecks` or `--strict` compiler option?  You should really define `next()`'s return type as `LazySequence<T> | undefined` or `LazySequence<T> | undefined | null` if you're going to check `seq.next() == undefined`.  Can you make this change?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder you can do a `reduceRight()` lazily without visiting all the values, but you need the callback to give you not `(accumulator: V, value: T)`  arguments, but something like `(accumulatorThunk: () => V, value: T)` instead.  Then in the callback impl you can inspect the `value` first before deciding to call `accumulatorThunk()`.  See [this demo implementation](https://tsplay.dev/wRJjYw) for how it would work.  This is easier in a lazy-first language like Haskell where a function call like `f(x)` does not evaluate `x` until the body of `f` needs it; to get that in JS you need a thunk.

Comment: I love functional programming and lazy evaluation but gosh @Sandy has posted and deleted like three questions about this so I'm not keen on writing up a big answer only for it to be rejected when I try to submit.  

Comment: @jcalz - Ah, fair enough if the callback supports the lazy eval **and** knows it doesn't need the value based on the accumulator value. Wasn't looking a the whole board. :-)

Comment: @Sandy if you don't want to change `LazySequence<T>`'s definition, then you should probably make `reduceRight` take an argument of something like `LazySequence<T | undefined>` and then check for the `value` being `undefined` to stop.  Like [this](https://tsplay.dev/NVKlMm).  If you're happy with this, or with changing `LazySequence`'s definition, or really anything that isn't deleting the question, let me know and I'd be happy to write up an answer.

Comment: @jcalz I was thinking of creating a array of type LazySequence and adding all the element in it then calling a reverse function and then on that calling my reduce function also It would be really cool if you could write im having hard time learning this would help a lo. One thing I can't change the definition i've to do it using the interface given I can't modify it

Comment: function reduce<T,V>(func: (v:V, t: T)=>V, seq: LazySequence<T>, start:V): V{
    if (seq.next() === undefined){
        return func(start,seq.value);
    }
    return reduce(func,seq.next(),func(start,seq.value));
}.                                                                                                                                           I want to call this method on my reduceRight reversed list so it reduces similarly but from right to left

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "all the elements"?  A `LazySequence<T>` is, by your definition, potentially infinite; there's no end to it.  Each one has a `next()` method that produces another `LazySequence<T>`.  If you're checking for `undefined` or `null` or something, then that should be part of either your definition of `LazySequence`, or your definition of `reduceRight()`.  Please answer this or at least acknowledge that you understand that it's an issue, or if you don't, then say that.

Comment: [This](https://tsplay.dev/NVKlMm) is probably the canonical definition of `reduceRight()` assuming you can terminate when `value` is `undefined`.  I'd recommend against explicitly reversing the list and then doing a left `reduce`; it's much simpler to just use rule that `reduceRight(fun, seq, init)` is either `init` or `fun(reduceRight(fun, seq.next(), init), seq.value)`.  It's pretty much the definition of a "right fold" as shown [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fold_(higher-order_function)#On_lists).

Comment: I was thinking wrong all the time I was thinking my seq is a an array with finite things and will have values which ill be accessing using next() method

Answer (score 1):

The `reduceRight()` list operation is also called [the "right fold"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fold_(higher-order_function)#On_lists).  The basic recursive definition for it is something like the following pseudocode:

```
function reduceRight(func, seq, start) {
   if (isEmpty(seq)) {
      return start;
   } else {
      let [first, rest] = getFirstAndRest(seq);
      return func( first, reduceRight(func, rest, start) );
   }
}
```

Note that the `func` callback takes two parameters; conventionally the *first* parameter is the value from the sequence, while the *second* parameter is the accumulator.  This is so that when you expand out what `reduceRight()` does in terms of repeated calls to `func`, the earlier values in the sequence will be on the left, and the later values will be on the right.  You have yours backwards from this, but I am putting it the conventional way from here on out.

See how there's no reason to try to "reverse" the sequence explicitly to implement this.  Because `reduceRight` on a non-empty sequence is written in terms of `reduceRight` of the rest of the sequence, this naturally associates to the right and therefore processes later list elements before earlier ones:  `reduceRight(f, sequenceOf(a, b, c), z)` will evaluate to `f(a, f(b, f(c, z)))`.

---

Of vital importance here: your definition of `LazySequence<T>`:

```
interface LazySequence<T> {
   value: T;
   next(): LazySequence<T>;
}
```

represents a truly **infinite** sequence.  According to this definition, a `LazySequence<T>` definitely has a `next()` method which definitely returns a `LazySequence<T>`.  (This assumes that you are using [the `--strictNullChecks` compiler option](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig/#strictNullChecks), which you should be.)  For example:

```
function iterate<T>(init: T, func: (v: T) => T): LazySequence<T> {
  return { value: init, next: () => iterate(func(init), func) }
}

const naturalNumbers = iterate(0, x => x + 1);
```

Here `naturalNumbers` corresponds to the infinite sequence `[0, 1, 2, 3, ...]`.  If I wanted to stop after, say, `10`, there's no way to do that directly.  You could define an element named `nil` whose `value` is `undefined` and whose `next()` points to itself, so your sequence only has a finite number of *distinct* elements, but it's still unending:

```
const nil: LazySequence<undefined> = { value: undefined, next: () => nil };

const fromArray = <T,>(x: T[], i = 0): LazySequence<T | undefined> =>
  i < x.length ? { value: x[i], next: () => fromArray(x, i + 1) } : nil;

const someNumbersThenUndefineds = fromArray([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]);
```

Here `someNumbersThenUndefineds` corresponds to the sequence `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, ...]`.

**The big issue**: Since folds like `reduceRight()` generally reduce *a whole sequence* to a single value, it is tricky to write a version of the algorithm that won't just get stuck in an infinite loop (or, more likely with functional programming, overflow the stack).  If you need to actually read every element of an infinite sequence, you're gonna have a bad time.

---

One way to proceed is to redefine `LazySequence<T>` so that it might possibly be `undefined`:

```
type LazySequence<T> = {
  value: T,
  next(): LazySequence<T>;
} | undefined;
```

Now you can write a finite sequence, by having the last element return `undefined` when you call `next()` on it:

```
const fromArray = <T,>(x: T[], i = 0): LazySequence<T> =>
  i < x.length ? { value: x[i], next: () => fromArray(x, i + 1) } : undefined

const someNumbers = fromArray([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]);
```

Now `someNumbers` more accurately represents `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]`.  Armed with this, we can finally write `reduceRight()`:

```
function reduceRight<T, V>(
  func: (value: T, accumulator: V) => V, 
  seq: LazySequence<T>, 
  start: V
): V {
  return seq ? func(seq.value, reduceRight(func, seq.next(), start)) : start;
}
```

And we can see it in action:

```
const sumOfSomeNumbers = reduceRight((v, a) => v + a, someNumbers, 0);
console.log(sumOfSomeNumbers) // 55
```

---

Another way to proceed is to keep the `LazySequence<T>` definition the way you have it, but to make `reduceRight()` bail out if `value` is `undefined`:

```
function reduceRight<T, V>(
  func: (value: T, accumulator: V) => V,
  seq: LazySequence<T | undefined>,
  start: V
): V {
  return seq.value === undefined ? start : func(seq.value, reduceRight(func, seq.next(), start))
}
```

This isn't as fully general as the first version, since it requires that you operate on a `LazySequence<T | undefined>` where a value can be `undefined`, but it works similarly.  If we apply that to `someNumbersThenUndefineds` above, we get the same result:

```
const sumOfSomeNumbers = reduceRight((v, a) => v + a, someNumbersThenUndefineds, 0);
console.log(sumOfSomeNumbers) // 55
```

---

Finally, what do we do if presented with actually infinite lists?  For each of the above implementations, the answer is: stack overflow or "too much recursion".  But you don't have to do that.  There is a way to write `reduceRight()` so that if the `func(value, accumulator)` callback doesn't need to consult `value`, then it can return early.  In languages that natively support [lazy evaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_evaluation) like Haskell, this happens for free.

If JavaScript worked that way, you could write `const f = (x, y) => y` and call `f(somethingThatMightBlowUp(), 1)` and it would return `1` without even evaluating `somethingThatMightBlowUp`.  Since it doesn't we have to *emulate* this by using a [thunk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thunk).  Instead of requiring the `accumulator` of type `V` be passed into `func()` directly, we accept `accThunk` of type `() => V`.  If we don't call `accThunk()`, then we can terminate the recursion.

Here's a truly lazy `reduceRight()` that expects an infinite `LazySequence<T>` with no necessarily `undefined` elements:

```
function reduceRight<T, V>(
  func: (val: T, accThunk: () => V) => V,
  seq: LazySequence<T>
): V {
  return func(seq.value, () => reduceRight(func, seq.next()));
}
```

Note that there's no `start` parameter.  The lists are infinite; we'll never need it. Instead, you'll find that the callback function `func` implementation will need to decide whether or not to call `accThunk()`, and if not, it will return something like `start`.  So the new `func` is like the old `func` and `start` together.

Let's add together the elements of `naturalNumbers` that are less than or equal to `10`:

```
const sumOfNaturalNumbersAtMostTen = reduceRight(
  (value, accThunk: (() => number)) => value > 10 ? 0 : accThunk() + value,
  naturalNumbers
);

console.log(sumOfNaturalNumbersAtMostTen); // 55
```

Hooray!

---

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99&ts=4.3.5#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEApeIA2AvJBvAsAFBFJKiSwLIBiAlsLQC4QAytUjUeRJpSjATxjIWILAIDKEAI4BXCMEQAeACoA+JAF5uhPnwBumeQC4kKgDS89wCAA9GACgCUp0eKlyFy9QG4rSAF8kAB8kWWAAEwgAM3oICL9iXT5o8PhGWgB7YCQAJ3jZRAAlWgBzAAtGVXMkADU1B1TFUwdDDBMzGoR4WTBZDBBGTNzTWqctDVqaqBlXMUkZeUUIVTVpxhBcxlGXOp09UnzGWVycmekkAH4kJvgHc4A6Nvka-IjCiBKKx1vpmQebPZnOtNownONTBxQYk9AEeMlSPBshwbrlMmAAIK5XIgARaJDVBq2UwqADaAF0arR8QAGXZuBaeZarCb+UjUpRIWwPDAKUqMcpXPBIZ4QUy2Um0SlkOzbJDOCao9FYnECBy2KlIADUSAAjOMgqZwlFYjYIvC9EjgCioOiIAA5XoAIwguS42miaMx2NxDlJNJqupqACYagBmGoAFhqAFYagA2GoAdhqAA4agBOQM08lORL+K023oAeWiEjtjrALrd+LeHy+lQcrS6400Gn02qQIGmFedrqgNTp+YRSELmV5PMypXuJbLvar-fGAHol0gYzH4RbAvC4YRyNA4IgkABJYCmpisdicHS8ejMXLRKhIBkeJbeDQEEeikkwviAxz0vMr5eCsvi8LuW77pQR4qK6YD0IMEDFsAACqkQxHEES1EYyCflupC3Bk2R5AUxRlJU1R1A0bI3GkLTfp0XbwD0fQDEMIx1K2kyWCOpDnHM7iLCBqghGE6GmvEaw0VCWyjP4uy1PsBxHCcZz-KKWiaNoxoYWaQoyYwSCmLc9zqThrykZ85E-GkfzSACsrAkgBngv4EEjoWhkMBgAmMm+Kw6RJEQaNouAijhRriZhNT-i0XFkLQGCBMOlrIoZnrKj6eLaIS6okhSmraHSvnAcyKiiYFmEhWoNEclyPJ8gKQphQxEpSjFspxYqGXeqq6qajq+qBEZCUYClfCec587VlAKjlAoaEmph7pKr1vr+oGIbhlGsYJsmaaZtmubjYiaXObO5aQJWM21pZDaOM2XbxR2OrdlNV19m6c0LVFZoDkgQ4Fsi44QJO05QBd02LkgK5rhuSSkO5pBQYeyAqLk-QCAyN4joRWQ5HWZHfJR9QODRtz0ZgJJdMxc3hAA1l1bacYqUzSbMz5AUJZU1SOClKXoKmnLRiimfZoo1AqzOE1Z3yNLZzn-P+zjgr+iP4SL6T40gF44swqwOPQTDU5r9EkvFKiAYJTLvgLfBCzkLURTrDCMB19hMxouuIfLotG2CNS3Aabka5NoDHDiGDXf2+Le8wDgBlyiq2J2+onaOZ0Q2Apb2oMJyYNHboYowACymQcLBOTaDL91k7x8oS0x8B08AjPylLGjAJ94KKhpGi6jSQqD6Y3Qt-TCo6hLNHh-nUefVA8np2OE4YFOM7Z9EucRwX8-F2XFcKHmMOruuW7uQEQA)